# Unable to update Abp.Zero.Ldap NuGet package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017, aspnetboilerplate, angular1.6

We are trying to update package "Abp.Zero.Ldap" using Visual Studio and NuGet package manager. I get an error:

> **Error:** Unable to resolve dependency 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement'. Source(s) used: 'nuget.org', 'Project MyGet', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages'.

And update another package "TM.Common.Text.Template" using Visual Studio and NuGet package manager. I get an error:

> **Error:** Unable to resolve dependencies. 'TM.Common.Text 1.0.1709.2303' is not compatible with 'TM.Common.Text.Template 1.0.1804.1301 constraint: TM.Common.Text (>= 1.0.1804.1301)'.

Could you please help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework?

Comment: And which version of ABP?

Comment: #aaron -- .Net FrameWork 4.6.1 and Current ABP 3.2.5. We are updating ABP to 3.5.0

Comment: Where is `TM.Common.Text` from?

Comment: @arron TM.Common.Text is client pacakge(Own).First we need ABP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in this issue: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3217

> [Abp.Zero.Ldap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.Zero.Ldap) package depends on below packages and they are pre releases.
>
> - System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (>= 4.5.0-preview1-26216-02)
> - System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (>= 4.5.0-preview1-26216-02)
>
> So if you include pre release packages while running Install-Package, it should work. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages#installing-and-updating-pre-release-packages.

> ```
> Install-Package Abp.Zero.Ldap -IncludePrerelease
> ```

Comment: It's Working.
Thank you @aaron